# Disable the display of keyboard on phone when I click on html input

Tags: javascript, html, input

How can I disable the display of keyboard on phones when I click on html input?

Because I display a custom keyboard, when on a phone I get two keyboards on the display.

```
<input style="width:160px; white-space: nowrap;"  type='text' ng-model="answer" ng-virtual-keyboard/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try setting your input to `readonly=true` it should stop appearing

```
<input style="width:160px; white-space: nowrap;" readonly="true" type='text' ng-model="answer" ng-virtual-keyboard/>
```